Pytorch Lightning, display validation metrics after few batches
In Pytorch Lightning, I would like to print loss and accuracy on Training batch and Validation dataset for each N steps (batches) for log and terminal.
The question is a bit similar to: Compute metrics/loss every n batches Pytorch Lightning
But the simplest solution didn't work for me, and the other one was looking to be over complicated for such basic functionality.

Meanwhile I found a possible answer, which is to use:  val_check_interval=n option at Trainer.
https://lightning.ai/docs/pytorch/stable/common/trainer.html#val-check-interval
From documentation:
How often within one training epoch to check the validation set. Can specify as float or int.

pass a float in the range [0.0, 1.0] to check after a fraction of the
training epoch.

pass an int to check after a fixed number of training batches.


